# The form in the active admin gives me the option of inserting an empty value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have this enum in the user model

```
  enum role: { Principal: 0, Teacher: 1 }
```

In the active admin, in the create user form, the input to insert the role gives me the option of inserting an empty string.

How can I make it that it only gives me the options `Principal` and `Teacher`?

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  actions :all, except: [:edit]
  permit_params :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :role


  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :email
      f.input :name
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
      f.input :role
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Comment: So how you want to show these options :- as a **dropdown** or as a **radio button** ??

Comment: I want to show them as a dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can pass a `include_blank: false` option

Means according to your code :-

```
....
....
f.input :role, include_blank: false
....
....
```